# Can we call new on arrow function?

Tags: javascript

I have a arrow function like the following:

```
var Test = () => {}
```

when I call:

```
new Test()
```

I get back:

```
VM110:1 Uncaught TypeError: Test is not a constructor(…)(anonymous function) @ VM110:1
```

we can't call `new` on arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow function can’t be used as a constructor: Normal functions support new via the internal method [[Construct]] and the property prototype. Arrow functions have neither, which is why

```
new (() => {})
```

throws an error.

Comment: For further reading, I'd also suggest the MDN page on them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: But an arrow function gets converted to a normal function right? [this](http://es6console.com/itl158ci/) seems to work just fine

Comment: That site appears to just translate es6 code to plain es5. There are no such thing as arrow functions in es5, so it is just converted to an anonymous function, which does not share this limitation.